# How to convert data in excel spreasheet forms into format for upload into a database

Tags: database, excel, format, vba

I need a good way to convert input data from 900 spreadsheets into a format suitable for  upload to a relational database (XML or flat file/s). The spreadsheets are multi-sheet, multi-line Excel 2007 each one consisting of 7 forms (so its definitely not a simple grid). There will be no formula data to get, just text, dates, integer data.

The 900 spreadsheets are all in the same format. 
I will need some kind of scripted solution.

I'm expecting I should be able to do this with excel macros (and I expect a fancy scriptable editor could do it too) or possibly SSIS.

Can someone tell me how you would approach this if it was yours to do?

Can anyone give a link to some technical info on a good way to do this?

I'm new to excel macros but used to programming and scripting languages, sql, others.

Why? We're using spreadsheet forms as an interim solution and I then need to get the data into the database.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to write data out to a plain text file. Use the CreateTextFile method of FileSystemObject. Documentation here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa265018(v=vs.60).aspx

There are many examples on the web of how to iterate over worksheets, capture the data and then use WriteLine method.

```
Sub ExampleTextFile()
    Dim fso as Object
    Dim oFile as Object
    Dim fullExport as String

    'Script that will capture data from worksheet belongs here _
    ' use the fullExport string variable to hold this data, for now we will _
    ' just create a dummy string for illustration purposes

    fullExport = "Example string contents that will be inserted in to my text file!"

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

   'In the next line, replace "C:\filename.txt" with the specified file you want to create

    set oFile = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\filename.txt", Overwrite:=True, unicode:=True)  

    oFile.WriteLine(fullExport) '<-- inserts the captured string to your new TXT file
    oFile.Close

    Set fso = Nothing
    Set oFile = Nothing

End Sub
```

If you have character encoding issues (I recently ran in to a problem with UTF16LE vs. UTF8 encoding, you will need to use the ADODB.Stream object, but that will require a different method of writing the file.